# MySql is not connecting on default port. Maybe because I had MAMP

Tags: mysql, macos

here´s my problem.

I was required to install MySql server as a local process to create a development environment. I use Mac OS X Yosemite. Pretty normal...

But...

After the installation... I noticed that mysqld connects on port 3307 instead of 3306. 
I also noticed that I had MAMP previously installed.

So... I removed MAMP (not sure if did it the right way... erased the folder and it´s contents)... Removed MySql (removed all mysql folders on var/local and on /etc)... Removed even Workbench (leap of faith...)

Reinstalled Mysql and........ NOTHING... still connects at 3307..

So I changed my.cnf in /etc... and...... NOTHING again... mysql seems to be ignoring my.cnf...

I´ve searched for all my.cnf files possible... and made sure that the port line is commented on all of then...

Please... I can´t sleep anymore... Help me!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem and i couldn't change mysql ports from configuration files.

***SOLUTION*** :: You should change your launch daemon configurations(or com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist) from /Library/LaunchDaemons

[MySQL Launch Daemon configuration link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/osx-installation-launchd.html)